# i want to append data, but its not working

Tags: angular

i want to append the data, as i run a loop it does not working,
this is my code

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of dropzone">
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  </form>
</div>

<button (click)="Append()">Hello</button>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var Dropzone: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  dropzone1: any;
  dropzone = new Array();
  count = 1;

  constructor() {
    this.dropzone.push({
      value: this.count
    });
  }

  Append(){
    this.count = this.count +1;
    console.log('this.count', this.count);
    this.dropzone.push({
        value: this.count
      });
  }

  hell(){
    console.log('working1');
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    // var Dropzone = require(‘dropzone’);
    var context = this;

try {

    new Dropzone('#my-awesome-dropzone', { maxFiles:10, addRemoveLinks: 

true, autoProcessQueue: false, init: function() {

        context.dropzone1 = this;

        this.on('addedfile', function(file) {

          console.log('file', file);

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          reader.onload = function () {

            // context.model_images.push({
            //   img: reader.result,
            //   name: file.name
            // });

          };

          // console.log(‘in base 64 chk model’, context.model_images);
          // context.model_images.push(file);

          if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            // this is not an image, so Dropzone doesn’t create a thumbnail.
            // set a default thumbnail:
            // you could of course generate another image yourself here,
            // and set it as a data url.
          }

        });

        this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
          // formData.append(‘property’, context.property_id);
          // formData.append(‘image’, file);
        });

        this.on('error', function(file, response) {
          // $(file.previewElement).find(‘.dz-error-message’).text(response.file_name);
          // context.error_count++;
          // console.log(response);
        });

        this.on('queuecomplete', function(){
          // $(‘#myloader’).removeClass(‘cssload-container’);
          // $(‘#loader_container’).removeClass(‘floatingBarsG’);
          // $(‘.blockG’).addClass(‘myopc’);
          // if(context.error_count>0){
          //     toastr.error(‘Error uploading images.’);
          // }
          // else{
          //      toastr.success(‘Property added successfully.’);
          //      context.navigate();
          // }
        });

        this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
          console.log('remove file', file);

          // for (var i = 0; i < context.model_images.length; i++) {
          //   if (context.model_images[i].name === file.name)context.model_images.splice(i,1);
          // }
          // console.log(‘after remove file’, context.model_images);
        });

        this.on("processing", function() {
          this.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
        });

        // context.dropzone_1 = this;
      }

    });

  }

  catch(err){
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('error');
  }

}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hell();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that it is not appending?

Comment: Saying "it's not working" is not particularly descriptive. We need to know what you expected to happen, what actually did happen and what errors were produced along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{data.value}}` inside form in some form control/group. Also, your loop generates form with the same id(probably, it is unnecessary behavior).
And it`s not how you should deal with forms in Angular. Read [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is working fine. The reason you are not seeing any change visually is because `from` tag itself is just a wrapper, it doesn't have any display. What you can do is add an input tag inside your form. In this way you will be able to see the new form appending.

Make your HTML like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dropzone;let i = index">
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone{{id}}">
    <input placeholder="I'm input in form {{i+1}}" >
  </form>
</div>

<button (click)="Append()">Hello</button>
```

You can see the working **stackblitz** demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlbkpx)